# Trying to use Mule as http proxy

Tags: mule

I tried to use mule as simple http proxy but seeing cookies that are send from the actual endpoint server is not passed on to the the client. Mule response has only one cookie.

```
<flow name="HelloWorld" doc:name="HelloWorld">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8888" doc:name="Http Endpoint"/>


        <http:outbound-endpoint
        method="GET" exchange-pattern="request-response"
        address="http://www.google.com"
        contentType="text/html" doc:name="HTTP" />

    </flow>
```

Comment: Tested with Mule Studio 3.5.0 using `curl -I http://localhost:8888`, and I can see the same two Set-Cookie headers as with `curl -I http://www.google.com`.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but i am not seeing the same when I do curl or from browser, are you doing some settings , some xml entry, for enabling cookies.

Comment: This will not work out-of-the-box for a basic browser, I added an answer where I try to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not passing the cookies to the client, but the fact that the cookies you receive will point to .google.com domain, so a basic web browser will probably reject them for security reasons when they come from localhost domain, and even if they were not rejected, they would not be sent along a subsequent call to localhost.

Now, the cookies come from the http outbound as a list that you can iterate and update with something like

```
#[foreach (cookie: message.inboundProperties['Set-Cookie']) {cookie.domain='localhost'}]
```

but you will also need to check for the existence of Set-Cookie property to not produce a null pointer exception when no cookies are set by the server.

for debugging your proxy app, you can/should also log the message you receive from the http outbound to see if cookies are present.

From the client/browser to the proxied server, I think the cookies should work just fine, as there is no domain data involved.